# Automatically Scroll Page from Top to Bottom, then Back Up (and Repeat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to figure out how to, upon pageload, automatically scroll to the bottom of a page (which has been described sufficiently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621286/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-a-page-up-if-slidedown-goes-of-the-bottom-of-the)) and then scroll back up automatically upon reaching the bottom of the page. I can find the automatic scrolling to the bottom, but I can't figure out how to identify when I'm at the bottom of the page, and how to scroll back up when I am. I'd do this using generic Javascript (or JQuery).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/yjYJ4/

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
});
```

You can view the demo in full screen here: http://jsfiddle.net/yjYJ4/embedded/result/

Change the number "1000" if you want to increase or decrease speed.

Works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE 6-9.

EDIT:

If you need it to repeat forever (not recommended...) you could do like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QUCWe/

Comment: I need it to repeat though. This works great for one iteration, but how can I make it do that forever?

Comment: In that case, you could do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bqwgt/  although I would recommend against it as it might crash some users' browsers.

Comment: Ah, thanks! This works perfectly on JSFiddle but doesn't load on the browser. Hmm. I'll play around with it, but at least the code works in theory!

Comment: I used your code in asp.net along with timer control, which calls the function on routine. so it keeps on oscillating up and down infinitely.

Comment: is it possible to have an onclick on anywhere of the screen cancel the autoscroll?

Answer (score 6):

here is the example using Pure JavaScript

```js
<script type="application/javascript">

var Height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
var currentHeight = 0;
var bool = true;
var step = 5;
var speed = 10;
var interval = setInterval(scrollpage, speed)

function scrollpage() {
    if (currentHeight < 0 || currentHeight > Height) 
        bool = !bool;
    if (bool) {
        window.scrollTo(0, currentHeight += step);
    } else {
        // if you don't want to continue scroll 
        // clearInterval(interval) use clearInterval
        window.scrollTo(0, currentHeight -= step);
    }
}

</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css"> 

#top {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 10000px;
}
#bottom {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

Comment: Was useful. Thanks. I was looking for a code that would not use jquery. And found this one...

Comment: Thanks for adding Javascript solution

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function as an argument, which will be called when the end has reached. I've just written a jQuery plugin for this purpose. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kKaWZ/**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.downAndUp = function(time, repeat){
        var elem = this;
        (function dap(){
            elem.animate({scrollTop:elem.outerHeight()}, time, function(){
                elem.animate({scrollTop:0}, time, function(){
                    if(--repeat) dap();
                });
            });
        })();
    }
})(jQuery);
$("html").downAndUp(2000, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the suggested infinite scroll JSFiddle code will work in firefox however will not work in Chrome/Chromium without a valid

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

tag at the start of ones page. [Per This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787380/jquery-window-height-function-does-not-return-actual-window-height)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: '1000' }, 500, function(){
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: '0' }, 500, function(){
        $("body").animate({ scrollTop: '1000' }, 500);
    });
});
```