# Auto scroll the scroll bar Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i want to make the scroll bar to auto scroll in my upcoming events and after some seconds it will scroll back to top again i want it to continuosly scrolling up and down in a slow pace. Can someone help me about this or give me some ideas? Don't have an idea. Im just starting to learn javascript.

here's a picture.

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107251/automatically-scroll-page-from-top-to-bottom-then-back-up-and-repeat

Comment: atleast put your some code to try for us.

Comment: window.scroll(x-coord, y-coord) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.scrollTop()` function in jquery [jQuery Scrolltop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and `setTimeout` for timer

html

```
<p><button id="scroll">scrollTop()</button></p>
<div id="test"></div>
```

css

```
#test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1000px;
    background: green;
}
```

javascript

```
$('#scroll').click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#test').css('top')
    }, 800, function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: 0
          }, 800);
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

i try to create simple example in [jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qrr8Ld7q/1/)

Comment: How can i slow down the scrolling sir?

Comment: change 800 value as you like, it mean animated duration, see here for detail http://api.jquery.com/animate/